# How to access a FQQN with Spring JMS?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-artemis

My Artemis broker is configured as follows:

```
<address name="PublishSubscribeWithPreDefinedQueues">
  <multicast>
    <queue name="Queue1"/>
    <queue name="Queue2"/>
  </multicast>
</address>
```

How do I tell my consuming client to connect to Queue1? According to [the docs](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names) I have to separate address name and queue name with `::` but I can't get it working.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "PublishSubscribeWithPreDefinedQueues::Queue1")
```

This will create a new address called `PublishSubscribeWithPreDefinedQueues::Queue1`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you trying to achieve is a shared durable consumer. Multiple Listeners, but load balance multiple consumers of same FQQN.

So I had exactly the same question and I work with spring boot. I looked a bit into spring boot and saw that the @JmsListener is setting up a MessagingMessageListenerAdapter which is a MessageListener adapter that invokes your defined method.
The interesting part is the the AbstractMessageListenerContainer which is a

> Abstract base class for Spring message listener container
>   implementations. Can either host a standard JMS
>   javax.jms.MessageListener or Spring's SessionAwareMessageListener for
>   actual message processing.

There is a method `getDefaultSubscriptionName(Object messageListener)` which gets your Message listener.
If we look at the implemenation:

```
    protected String getDefaultSubscriptionName(Object messageListener) {
    if (messageListener instanceof SubscriptionNameProvider) {
        return ((SubscriptionNameProvider) messageListener).getSubscriptionName();
    }
    else {
        return messageListener.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

So if we don't provide a subscription name spring will take org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter as the name because all @JmsListeners are a instance of MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.

So to configure it we have to set our factory with the subscription shared and durable to true.

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new BeanFactoryDestinationResolver(beanFactory)); //or new DynamicDestinationResolver()
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

and now you can use the Annotation as followed:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "PublishSubscribeWithPreDefinedQueues", containerFactory="containerFactory", subscription="Queue1")
```

and the subscription name is now the queue name of your address.